# How to Store Class in a Variable Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

i want to store a Class in a variable, the purpose is to check if other variable is an instanceOf the class 
Here is My Code :

```
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.vend_list -> {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, vendingList)
                    id = VendListClass
                }
                R.id.label -> {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, label)
                    id = LabelClass
                }
                R.id.home -> {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mainMenu)
                    id = MainMenuClass
                }
                R.id.statistic -> {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, statistic)
                    id = StatisticClass
                }
                else -> {}
            }

            for(fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments){
                if(fragment !is id){
                    remove(fragment)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know your exact requirement. But it probably could be designed in other ways, enum? sealed classes? inheritances?

Anyway, straight to your question, hope this helps:

```
val listCls = List::class
val strCls = String::class

val listObj = listOf(1,2,3)

println("check listObj and listCls: ${listCls.isInstance(listObj)}")
println("check listObj and strCls: ${strCls.isInstance(listObj)}")
```

output:

```
check listObj and listCls: true
check listObj and strCls: false
```

Comment: what is the type of listCls and strCls? I need to store a different Class in one variable using `when()` conditions. and then i will check if other object is an instance of that Class

Comment: @Jooo21 the two `*Cls` variable is with type `KClass` you can of course use one variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can store a class reference in a `KClass<*>` variable using `::class` or in a `Class<*>` variable using `::class.java`

So based on your original code, this is how you could do it

```
            // this has to be a nullable type because of your else option
            var id: KClass<*>? = null
    
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.vend_list -> {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, vendingList)
                    id = VendListClass::class
                }
                R.id.label -> {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, label)
                    id = LabelClass::class
                }
                R.id.home -> {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mainMenu)
                    id = MainMenuClass::class
                }
                R.id.statistic -> {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, statistic)
                    id = StatisticClass::class
                }
                else -> {}
            }

            for(fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments){
                // if the else option from when has to remove all
                // fragments, just flip the condition to
                // if(id == null || id.isInstance(fragment))
                if(id != null && id.isInstance(fragment)){
                    remove(fragment)
                }
            }
```

Comment: This was my breakthrough: `myClass.isInstance(obj)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Kent for helping, but I figured out how to solve this in an ineffective way.

Here is my code:

```
val obj1 = Object1()
val obj2 = Object2()
val obj3 = Object3()
val obj4 = Object4()

var id : SuperObject? = null

when(certainConditions) {
   option1 -> id = Object1()
   option2 -> id = Object2()
   option3 -> id = Object3()
   option4 -> id = Object4()
}

val otherObject = Object1()

if(id == otherObject) {
    //process logic
}
```

I'm still looking for the more effective way though.
If anyone found out a better way, please share your answer.

Comment: it's called an enum